# Нужна помощь в парсинге с помощью Python beafutifulsoup и lxml

Tags: python, парсер

Я использую beautifulsoup и lxml, хочу спарсить цену (5.47) которая указана в "PricePerItem" код ниже. Помогите пожалуйста.

```
<div class="js-product-card-footer fs-product-card__footer-container" data-options='{
"productId" : "5201799-EA-000PNS" ,
"productName": "Value Standard Milk",
"productVariants" :[],
"restricted" : "false" ,
"tobacco" : false,
"liquor" : false ,
"loginRegisterModalTitle" : "You need to login first" ,
"loginRegisterBodyCopy" : "Sign up or login to access my favourites" ,
"ProductDetails" : {
"PriceMode" :"ea",
"PricePerItem" : "5.47" ,
"HasMultiBuyDeal" : false ,
"MultiBuyDeal" : "" ,
"PricePerBaseUnitText" : "" ,
"ClubCardPriceText": null,
"MultiBuyBasePrice" : "" ,
"MultiBuyPrice" : "" ,
"MultiBuyQuantity" : "" ,
"ProductLimitText" : "",
"PromoBadgeImageLabel": "Everyday Low",
"ShowPromotionViewAllModal": false,
"registrationURL": "/shop/signup"
}}'>
</div>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

с помощью библиотеки BeautifulSoup можно получить data-option в виде строки, а затем с помощью json преобразовать данную строку в словарь, в котором легко получить доступ к любому полю

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
do = soup.find('div')['data-options']
dataOption = json.loads(do.replace('\n',''))
print(dataOption["ProductDetails"]["PricePerItem"])
```

Comment: html  - это строка с вашим html кодом